# row delete but not removing the corersponding value from the total from the label using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Currently working on jquery date picker with my current code where I can able to clone the row and i can able to add years and months.  But when i try click add more it will create one more row and again i can able to add from date and to date it was calculating perfectly but when i click the delete button it was deleting the row but not removing the corresponding value.

here is what i tired for delete

```
 $(document).on('click', ".btn_less1", function() {
    var len = $('.cloned-row3').length;
    if (len > 1) {
      $(this).closest(".btn_less1").parent().parent().parent().remove();
      uppdiff();
    }    
 });
```

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/bqgjro6d/52/) for rest of the code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order you defined your function was wrong, the function `uppdiff` was not found since it was defined much later. I rearranged your code as shown below:

```
$(function() {
  var diffDays = 0;
  $.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    yearRange: "-100:+0",
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: new Date(),
    showButtonPanel: false,
    beforeShow: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);

      }, 0);
    }

  });
  var valid = true;

  function uppdiff() {
    if (valid) {
      var dateStart = [];
      var dateEnd = [];
      $.each($('.datepicker'), function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass('startDate'))
          dateStart.push($(this).datepicker('getDate'))
        else
          dateEnd.push($(this).datepicker('getDate'))
      });
      diffDays = 0;
      $.each(dateStart, function(key, value) {
        $.each(dateStart, function(key2, value) {
          if (key !== key2 && !(dateStart[key] >= dateEnd[key2] || dateEnd[key] <= dateStart[key2])) {
            alert('Date ranges overlap');
            valid = false;
            return valid;
          }
        });
        diffDays += parseInt((dateEnd[key] - dateStart[key]) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        return valid;
      });
      var year = parseInt(diffDays / 365);
      var date = diffDays - (365 * year);
      var month = parseInt(date / 30);



      //document.getElementById("txt_expy").innerHTML = year + " year";
      //document.getElementById("txt_expm").innerHTML = month + " Month";

            if(year >= 0){
                $("#txt_expy").text(year + " year");
            }

            if(month >= 0){
                $("#txt_expy").text(month + " Month");
            }
    }
  }

  $(".cloned-row3").find(".datepicker").removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
  var count = 0;
  $(document).on("click", ".exp_add_button", function() {
    var $clone = $('.cloned-row3:eq(0)').clone(true, true);
    $clone.find('[id]').each(function() {
      this.id += 'someotherpart'
    });
    $clone.find('.btn_more').after("<input type='button' value='Delete Row' class='btn_less1 selbtnless' id='buttonless'/>")
    $clone.attr('id', "added" + (++count));
    /*$clone.find(".degree_Description").attr('disabled', true).val('');*/
    $clone.find("input.startDate,input.endDate")
      .val('')
      .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
      .removeData('datepicker')
      .unbind()
      .datepicker();
    $(this).parents('.wrk_exp').after($clone);
  });

  $(document).on('change', ".datepicker", function() {
    var valid = true;

    $.each($('.datepicker'), function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        valid = false;
        return false;
      }
      uppdiff();
    });
    uppdiff();


  });

  $(document).on('click', ".btn_less1", function() {
    var len = $('.cloned-row3').length;
    if (len > 1) {
      $(this).closest(".btn_less1").parent().parent().parent().remove();
      uppdiff();
    }
  });
});
```

[Here is the **updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5L6jumdy/1/)

Comment: thanks for the reply there is one small issue is there when i select the from date for example 01/01/2015 initially it was showing -45 then if i select the to date now it was coming the correct value :(

Comment: I think that somewhere u need to add a condition where, if the value is _less than 0_ then you do _not_update the total years of experience.

Comment: is that possible can you please update the fiddle which you told me it would be help ful

Comment: I just updated the codes in my answer and the link to the updated JSFiddle

Comment: is that possible can you please create chat invite :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97588/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-ahs-n).

Comment: can you please join in the chat :(